# Remove/Stop function on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a site running this plugin...
http://classic.formstone.it/components/zoomer

the function allows an image to be zoomed in and out using CSS transforms and by default there are 2 controls, zoom in and zoom out.

I want to add a reset control that puts the image back to its default state before it had been zoomed.

I have the following...

```
$('.reset').on('click',function(){
  $('.zoomer-holder').css(
    'transform','translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0px) scale(0.2525, 0.2525)'
  );
});
```

The above works in a jsfiddle demo fine, but when used side by side with the zoomer plugin it fails to do anything, as though the plugin prevents the image from being altered.

Can anybody shed any light on what may be happening?

Js Fiddle...
http://jsfiddle.net/fxuqqgLh/1/

Comment: could you add `zoomer` plugin also into your jsfiddle and post the jsfiddle here

Comment: Here it is @dreamweiver http://jsfiddle.net/fxuqqgLh/1/

Answer (score 0):

The plugin seems to use an animation loop that calls a `_render()` function over and over to control zooming and panning of the held images. The render function is constantly called - apparently multiple times a second:

```
function _render() {
    for (var i = 0, count = $instances.length; i < count; i++) {
        var data = $instances.eq(i).data("zoomer");

        if (typeof data === "object") {
            // Update image and position values
            data = _updateValues(data);
            data.lastAction = data.action;

            // Update DOM
            if (transformSupported) {
                var scaleX = data.imageWidth / data.naturalWidth,
                    scaleY = data.imageHeight / data.naturalHeight;

                data.$positioner.css(_prefix("transform", "translate3d(" + data.positionerLeft + "px, " + data.positionerTop + "px, 0)"));
                data.$holder.css(_prefix("transform", "translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) scale(" + scaleX + "," + scaleY + ")"));
            } else {
                data.$positioner.css({
                    left: data.positionerLeft,
                    top: data.positionerTop
                });
                data.$holder.css({
                    left: data.imageLeft,
                    top: data.imageTop,
                    width: data.imageWidth,
                    height: data.imageHeight
                });
            }

            // Run callback function
            if (data.callback) {
                data.callback.apply(data.$zoomer, [
                    (data.imageWidth - data.minWidth) / (data.maxWidth - data.minWidth)
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `_render()` function uses the properties defined on `data.imageWidth` and `data.imageHeight` to set the size of the image each animation cycle and these properties are themselves defined by `data.targetImageWidth` and `data.targetImageHeight`. The plugin moves the width/height properties towards the targetWidth/targetHeight properties over time to create the animation.

In the plugin, try putting a breakpoint at the line in `_render()`:

```
var scaleX = data.imageWidth / data.naturalWidth,
```

and then use your javascript console to play with different values for `imageWidth`, `imageHeight`, `targetImageWidth` and `targetImageHeight`. You can see how the plugin works.

To create your 'reset' button, you will have to write some code that manipulates the `data` object of the zoom plugin rather than setting css directly. You should download and extend the plugin's source code - maybe start around the `controls` object under `options`:

```
var options = {
    callback: $.noop,
    controls: {
        position: "bottom",
        zoomIn: null,
        zoomOut: null,
        next: null,
        previous: null
    },
    customClass: "",
    enertia: 0.2,
    increment: 0.01,
    marginMin: 30, // Min bounds
    marginMax: 100, // Max bounds
    retina: false,
    source: null
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response @Oliver, I think I may have to find an alternative plugin - seems a bit of a headache for such a simple thing!

Comment: @Liam Yes, I would have efficiency concerns about this plugin given that it never stops animating itself.

Comment: Is it possible to stop the function from running @Oliver and then reinitialise it later on?

Comment: @Liam Probably, but you'd have to significantly rework the plugin to do that.

Answer (score -1):

```
$( ".reset" ).click(function() {
  //Your Code
});
```

Why don't you use this instead of:

```
$('.reset').on('click',function(){
  $('.zoomer-holder').css(
    'transform','translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0px) scale(0.2525, 0.2525)'
  );
});
```